# How to get fetched models when collection is lazy loaded?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a long list of videos and I've added lazy loading to this list:

```
//file videos.js
loadMore: function(){
   this.fetch({
       add: true, //add to collection 
       data: {
           limit: this.limit, 
           offset: this.offset
       }
   });
   this.offset += this.limit;
}
```

This fetch trigger an `add` event to the view.

```
//file videosView.js
initialize : function() {
    collection.bind('add', this.addVideo, this);
},

addVideo: function() {
    //how can I get the added models?
},
```

**In the view, how can I get the models that was added?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ask for it in your add callback function:

```
addVideo: function(video) {
    // the model that was added is in the video variable
}
```